# Sony Xperia S ADB Driver

Tags: sony, sony-xperia

Please do not minus or block this question, because First I contacted Sony Support and they recommended me to ask this question here.

I would like to create some program for my Sony XPeria S (LT26i), but I cannot enable uSB debugging. Looks like Android Studio can not detect my phone because ADB drivers are not installed correctly.

I have Android 4.1.2 (Jelly Bean) on my Sony Xperia S (LT26i). It is last official update as I understand. 
If I want to download ADB drivers for it and I go to this page http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/drivers/
I can see only drivers for Xperia S for ICS (Android 4.0) and for GB (Android 2.3).

Maybe someone know link, where I can download correct drivers or another solution to this issue?

Or maybe it is not possible, because Sony made an update for Xperia S to 4.1.2 but they forgot to make a driver for this version :)?

Some more history and details. I tried to install this driver first "[Drivers] FlashTool Xperia Driver Pack (v1.5) [20140318]" available by this link
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2635830, but each time I get this error message
"DPInst.exe does not execute on your current Operating System".
I have Windows 7 64bits.

Comment: This post is off topic, because you are referring to an off-site resource. You may want to contact Sony support for drivers.

Comment: Sony support officially recommended me to create my question here :) Please do not delete this question.

Comment: If your question gets closed or deleted by mods, I apologize... Mainly for you having to deal with a Sony Support rep not wanting to deal with your question. But hey, who likes tech support? Good luck finding your drivers. I suggest asking on Reddit or xda.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try using the driver for ICS for Xperia S?  If that doesn't work, I would suggest installing Sony PC Companion:

http://support.sonymobile.com/global-en/tools/pc-companion/

PC Companion should automatically install the correct drivers for you when you connect your phone via USB.

Comment: I tried to install driver for ICS. It does not work (Or maybe I tried to install it in a wrong way). Can you give me link with ICS driver installation guide?  PC Companion I already installed, but looks like in my case driver is not installed.

I have non english windows version (Windows 7 64bit Russian), I read in the internet that sometimes with non english windows people have a problems.

Comment: For future reference - the link to the ICS drivers: http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/drivers/xperia-s-driver-for-ics/